# Esp8266 not working

Tags: esp8266

I connected all the pins as in datasheet, except `ch_pd`.
But when I connect `ch_pd` to 3.3 V , the red light on `esp8266` goes dim. I used 3.3 V, 250 mA power supply. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Link to datasheet? Link to ESP8266 device used? Image of how you have wired it up?

Comment: Recommended power supply sourcing capabilities are about 1A. In the firmware upgrading mode WiFi is possibly disabled, so it needs much less power.